# how to make a high pass filter?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, filtering, fft

I have a 3D data matrix of sea level data (time, y, x) and I found the power spectrum by taking the square of the FFT but there are low frequencies that are really dominant. I want to get rid of those low frequencies by applying a high pass filter... how would I go about doing that? 
Example of data set and structure/code is below:

This is the data set and creating the arrays:

```
Yearmin = 2018
Yearmax = 2019
year_len = Yearmax - Yearmin + 1.0 # number of years

direcInput = "filepath"
a = s.Dataset(direcInput+"test.nc", mode='r') 

#creating arrays
lat = a.variables["latitude"][:] 
lon = a.variables["longitude"][:] 
time1 = a.variables["time"][:] #DAYS SINCE JAN 1ST 1950
sla = a.variables["sla"][:,:,:] #t, y, x
time = Yearmin + (year_len * (time1 - np.min(time1)) / ( np.max(time1) - np.min(time1))) 


#detrending and normalizing data 
def standardize(y, detrend = True, normalize = True):
    if detrend == True:
        y = signal.detrend(y, axis=0)
    y = (y - np.mean(y, axis=0))
    if normalize == True:
        y = y / np.std(y, axis=0)
    return y

sla_standard = standardize(sla)

print(sla_standard.shape) = (710, 81, 320)


#fft
fft = np.fft.rfft(sla_standard, axis=0)
spec = np.square(abs(fft))

frequencies = (0, nyquist, df)


#PLOTTING THE FREQUENCIES VS SPECTRUM FOR A FEW DIFFERENT SPATIAL LOCATIONS
plt.plot(frequencies, spec[:, 68,85])
plt.plot(frequencies, spec[:, 23,235])
plt.plot(frequencies, spec[:, 39,178])
plt.plot(frequencies, spec[:, 30,149])
plt.xlim(0,.05)
plt.show()
```

[image: plot of frequencies and power spectrum]

My goal is to make a high pass filter of the ORIGINAL time series (sla_standard) to remove the two really big peaks. Which type of filter should I use? Thank you!

Comment: A high pass is effectively the subtraction of a low pass filtered version. Do you know how to implement a low pass?

Comment: You can use any filter you want, you have to decide the filter shape according to your needs. A simple (non-causal) high pass filter is to perform the Fourier transform of your signal, set to zero the lower frequencies, and then to inverse Fourier transform.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `.axes.Axes.set_ylim` to set the y-axis limit.

> `Axes.set_ylim(self, left=None, right=None, emit=True, auto=False, *, ymin=None, ymax=None)`

So in your case `ymin=None` and you set ymax for example to `ymax=60000` before you start plotting.

Thus `plt.ylim(ymin=None, ymax=60000)`.

Taking out data should not be done here because its "falsifying results". What you actually want is to zoom in on the chart. The person who reads the chart independently from you would interpret the data falsely if not made aware in advance. Peaks that go off the chart are okay because everybody understands that.

Or:

Directly replacement of certain values in an array (arr):

`arr[arr > ori] = dest`

For example in your case `ori=60000` and `dest=1`

All values larger ">" than 60k are replaces by 1.

Comment: Ah yeah... but I would like to apply a high pass filter to the original time series. not just change the axes to remove the first and second peak in the FFT power spec

Comment: added method of replacing high values in an arry by whatevery value you want.

Comment: Will the person who just down-voted look at the original text of OP and remove the down-vote. To be clear OP stated: "My goal is to make a high pass filter to remove the two really big peaks. Which type of filter should I use? Thank you!". Replacement of values in a chart via filters details to change data in an array before you can display it!!

Answer (score 0):

**The different filters:** As you state a filter acts on the frequencies of your signal. Different filter shapes exist and some of them have complex expressions because they need to be implemented in real time processing (causal). However in your case, you seem to post process the data. You can use the Fourier Transform, that requires all the data (non causal).

**The filter to choose:** Consequently you can directly perform you filtering operation in the Fourier domain by applying a mask on your frequencies. If you want to remove frequencies, I recommand you to use a binary mask made of 0 and 1. Why? Because it is the simplest filter you can think about. It is scientifically relevant to state that you completely removed some frequencies (say it and justify it). However it is more difficult to claim that you let some and attenuated a little bit others, and that you chose arbitrarily the attenuation factor...

**Python implementation**

```py
signal_fft = np.fft.rfft(sla_standard,axis=0)
mask = np.ones_like(sla_standard)
mask[freq_to_filter,...] = 0.0 # define here the frequencies to filter
filtered_signal = np.fft.irfft(mask*signal_fft,axis=0)
```